# Nothing ever could possibly go wrong

Tags: phrase-meaning

Let's say you are talking about the reason why sometimes you are complacent to some things. Can you say:

> I don't worry much, because sometimes, I feel that **nothing ever could possibly go wrong.**

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not terrible, but better is "nothing could ever possibly go wrong". When I google "ever could", I get 5.5 million results, as compared to "could ever", with 45.9 million. You can check for yourself.